# When migrating work items with links to a git repo in another project, links are not migrating

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

We are currently moving multiple projects between Azure Devops organizations by using the https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/ tool.

A lot of work items that are being migrated have links to git repos (commits, branches) that are from another project within the same organization.
When the tool is running, it's not able to find the repo if it's in another project.

Example warning from when the tool is running:

> GitRepositoryEnricher: Could not find source git repo - repo
> referenced: xy/mn

Under the Development section on the work items that have this links the following comments shows:

> Commit not found or no permission to access it.

All repos have been migrated before the work items and have the same names as in the source organization. I don't believe it's a permissions issue, as I can add the link manually.

Below is the config json file:

```
{
  "ChangeSetMappingFile": null,
  "Source": {
    "$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
    "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/sourceorg/",
    "Project": "sourceproject",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": true,
    "AuthenticationMode": "Prompt",
    "PersonalAccessToken": "PAT",
    "LanguageMaps": {
      "AreaPath": "Area",
      "IterationPath": "Iteration"
    }
  },
  "Target": {
    "$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
    "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/targetorg/",
    "Project": "targetproject",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": true,
    "AuthenticationMode": "Prompt",
    "PersonalAccessToken": "",
    "LanguageMaps": {
      "AreaPath": "Area",
      "IterationPath": "Iteration"
    }
  },
  "FieldMaps": [],
  "GitRepoMapping": null,
  "LogLevel": "Information",
    "Processors": [
    {
      "$type": "WorkItemMigrationConfig",
      "Enabled": true,
      "ReplayRevisions": true,
      "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
      "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
      "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
      "WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan', 'Test Case')",
      "WIQLOrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
      "LinkMigration": true,
      "AttachmentMigration": true,
      "AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\\temp\\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\\",
      "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": true,
      "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": true,
      "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
      "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": false,
      "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
      "AttachmentMaxSize": 480000000,
      "AttachRevisionHistory": false,
      "LinkMigrationSaveEachAsAdded": false,
      "GenerateMigrationComment": false,
      "NodeBasePaths": [],
      "WorkItemIDs": null
    }
  ],

  "Version": "11.11",
  "workaroundForQuerySOAPBugEnabled": false,
  "WorkItemTypeDefinition": {
    "sourceWorkItemTypeName": "targetWorkItemTypeName"
  }
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is not a bug tracker for open source tools. Please post an issue on the project's GitHub page. github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/issues

Answer (score 0):

Policies must be open equaly to allow the linkage, both projects (organizations as well) Must be part of the same Tenant.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).